# IdentityServer4 discovery document returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am following the quick start for ID Server 4 with one exception that I am working on a Mac with .NET Core 2.1.302.  Somehow when I navigate to `http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration` I get a 404:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.108ms 404
```

Here are the steps that I took:

1. Created a new MVC project `dotnet new mvc`
2. Added ID Server `dotnet add package IdentityServer4`
3. Modified my service configuration by adding

   ```
       services.AddIdentityServer()
           .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
           .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
           .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
   ```
4. Created Config.cs with:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
   {
       return new List<ApiResource>
       {
           new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
       };
   }

   public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
   {
       return new List<Client>
       {
           new Client
           {
               ClientId = "client",

               // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

               // secret for authentication
               ClientSecrets =
               {
                   new Secret("secret".Sha256())
               },

               // scopes that client has access to
               AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
           }
       };
   ```

When I navigate to http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration I get a 404 instead of the discovery document.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Missing from your list of of steps is adding `UseIdentityServer` inside of your `Startup`'s `Configure` method. It's covered in the official [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html?highlight=UseIdentityServer#configuring-the-pipeline) and looks something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseMvc(...);
}
```

`UseIdentityServer` adds the IdentityServer middleware into the ASP.NET Core pipeline. One of its responsibilities is to serve up the .well-known endpoints.